# Bash for loop / echo removing capitalized characters from string array

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I was trying to enumerate a bunch of files in bash and noticed the following strange error occuring.

The input string 'rtpwatcher_Class_Sync_License_Capture' gets echo'd as 'rtpwatcher_Class_ ync_ icense_Capture', seemingly removing uppercase characters at random.

Code:

```
hb_names=("rtpwatcher_Truckmove_Statemachine" "rtpwatcher_Class_Sync_License_Capture")
hb_test="rtpwatcher_Truckmove_Statemachine,rtpwatcher_Class_Sync_License_Capture"

for i in $(echo $hb_test | tr ',' '\n')
do
    echo $i
done

for hb in ${hb_names[@]}; do
    echo $hb
done
```

Output:

```
rtpwatcher_Truckmove_ tatemachine
rtpwatcher_Class_ ync_ icense_Capture
rtpwatcher_Truckmove_ tatemachine
rtpwatcher_Class_ ync_ icense_Capture
```

I've tried changing the string to only have one upper case character (rtpwatcher_Class_sync_license_capture) and the output was 'rtpwatcher_Class_sync_license_capture' as expected.

SOLVED:

```bash
for hb in "${hb_names[@]}"; do
    echo "${hb}"
done
```

Comment: under `bash 4.4.12` this code generates the expected output (ie, no characters are removed)

Comment: Cannot reproduce your issue on either `GNU bash, version 5.1.16(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)` or `GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin20)`.  Per  @markp-fuso comment, the code generates the expected output.

Comment: On `5.2.15` this generates the expected output as well...

Comment: BTW, `for i in $(anything)` is bad practice. Consider `IFS=, read -r -a hb_test_arr <<<"$hb_test"` and then `for i in "${hb_test[@]}"` if for some reason you can't just define `hb_test` as an array in the first place.

Comment: And you should be quoting `"${hb_names[@]}"` -- when you use just `${hb_names[@]}` without the quotes you're bug-for-bug compatible with `${hb_names[*]}`

Comment: And `echo "$i"`, not `echo $i` -- see [I just assigned a variable, but `echo $variable` shows something different!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378566/i-just-assigned-a-variable-but-echo-variable-shows-something-else)

Comment: Beyond that, I'd want to see an xtrace log from your script. `bash -x yourscript`, or add the line `set -x`. Likely you have a nonprintable character in your real script that got lost in the copy/paste into Stack Overflow, hence none of us being able to reproduce the problem; xtrace logs will include any such character escaped in printable form.

Comment: Have you changed the value of `IFS`? Like set it to something containing "S" and "L"?

Comment: Thanks Charles Duffy that indeed fixed it, seems like bash interprets the output if the quotes are missing. How can I mark your answer?

Comment: @SATANS'418 Which suggestion fixed it, quoting variables or looking for nonprinting characters or something else? Also, if it was a quoting problem, you should *also* check `IFS`, since a nonstandard value for that is a problem waiting to happen.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, given that quotes resolved the issue, what was happening there?  I could see a custom IFS stripping one of "S" or "L" but not both! Seems more like a set stripping using sed.  No problems with OP's original script using my version of bash (GNU bash, version 5.0.17(1)-release x86_64-pc-linux-gnu).

Comment: @EricMarceau If `IFS` is set to something containing *both* "S" and "L", it'll treat both as whitespace. Try `(hb_test="rtpwatcher_Truckmove_Statemachine,rtpwatcher_Class_Sync_License_Capture"; IFS="SL"; echo $hb_test | tr ',' '\n')` to see the effect (the parentheses are there to keep the weird `IFS` value from messing up your shell).

Comment: I was under the impression that **IFS** was a character/string considered as a **single** pattern for splitting.  I did not think that it was considered a **set** of distinct patterns, each one for splitting !!!  Is that what you are suggesting, given the behaviour for each of S and L ?

Comment: @EricMarceau `IFS` is treated as a set of whitespace characters, not a single pattern. According to [the POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_05), "The shell shall treat *each character of* the `IFS` as a delimiter" (emphasis added). Also, the default value of `IFS` consists of a space, a tab, and a newline (i.e. `IFS=$' \t\n'`), and you don't need that entire sequence in a string for it to be split as whitespace.

Comment: @GordonDavisson, thank you!  You learn every day!